# How do I center a JPanel containing a FlowLayout?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, layout-manager

I have a JPanel containing a few components, laying them out with a FlowLayout, so that they will wrap if necessary and i want to center this JPanel in a JFrame.
I tried to use a BoxLayout with a VerticalGlue, but it doesn't center it completely.
Here is a simple SSCCE, which demonstrates my problem, because i dont think i can explain it well:

```
import javax.swing.*;
public class Test extends JFrame {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }
    public Test() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        getContentPane().setLayout(new BoxLayout(getContentPane(), BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        getContentPane().add(Box.createVerticalGlue());
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add(new JButton("New button"));
        panel.add(new JButton("New button"));
        getContentPane().add(panel);
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

If the window is wide enough to fit both buttons next to each other, it almost seems centered:

[image]

But if its too small you can clearly see my problem:

[image]

The problem is that the JPanel takes the lower half of the JFrame and the Glue the upper half:

[image]

I have tried other LayoutManagers aswell, but I couldn't fix this problem yet.

EDIT:

With a BorderLayout and the JPanel placed in the center the buttons appear at the top because the JPanel expands to the size of the ContentPane of the JFrame:

[image]

With a GridBagLayout it looks perfect with everything next to each other. But if the components are wrapped they disappear:

[image]

[image]

Using a MigLayout, the buttons wont wrap anymore:

[image]

**EDIT:**
The solution i used is a combination of the [Wrap Layout](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/06/wrap-layout/) with the GridBagLayout:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
class Test extends JFrame {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }
    Test() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        GridBagLayout gridBagLayout = new GridBagLayout();
        gridBagLayout.columnWeights = new double[]{1.0};
        getContentPane().setLayout(gridBagLayout);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new WrapLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gbc_panel = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_panel.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        getContentPane().add(panel, gbc_panel);
        panel.add(new JButton("New button"));
        panel.add(new JButton("New button"));
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd try to nest the FlowLayout in the CENTER of a BorderLayout...

Comment: If these are the only components on the panel and you want to be exact with their position, I would suggest using NullLayout (setLayout(null)) and utilizing setBounds(). https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/none.html                                  In order to fix your resizing issue, just make the parameters of the setBounds() method proportional to the size of the JFrame.

Comment: @javaislife `I would suggest using NullLayout (setLayout(null)) and utilizing setBounds().`: worst advice one can give. Never, ever use null-layout! Simply wrapping the panel into a surrounding panel with gridbaglayout and the default constraint will do what the OP wants

Comment: I would use `MigLayout` for that, and for any other cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The problem is that the JPanel takes the lower half of the JFrame and the Glue the upper half:

The problem is that the BoxLayout will allow components to grow up to the maximum size of the component. In the case of a panel, the maximum size is the maximum Integer value so both the glue and the panel get equal amounts of space. So if you want to use a BoxLayout, you need to override the `getMaximumSize()` method to return the preferred size of the panel.

> I tried to use a BoxLayout with a VerticalGlue, but it doesn't center it completely.

After the above change you then need to use verticalGlue twice:

```
Box box = new Box.createVerticalBox(); 
box.add( Box.createVerticalGlue() );
box.add( panel );
box.add( Box.createVerticalGlue() );
```

Now you will have equal amounts of space above and below the panel. However, this still won't work when components wrap to the next line because the `FlowLayout` does not recalculate the height based on the wrapped components. So in this case you can replace the `FlowLayout` with the [Wrap Layout](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/06/wrap-layout/) which simply extends `FlowLayout` to calculate the wrapped height correctly.

Or instead of using a BoxLayout, you can use a GridBagLayout. By default components added to the GridBagLayout will be centered horizontally and vertically. You would still need the panel with the `WrapLayout`

Comment: The solution i used is a combination of the Wrap Layout with the GridBagLayout as you recommended.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example using the [WrapLayout](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/06/wrap-layout/) mentioned by [camickr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/131872/camickr).  I had to mess with max size of the wrap panel which is a bit of a hack, but I think it's enough to get you pointed in the right direction.

```
public class Test extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        JPanel boxPanel = new JPanel();
        boxPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(boxPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        boxPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.GREEN, 1));

        JPanel wrapPanel = new JPanel();

        // hack of panel max size
        wrapPanel.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(99999, 0));
        wrapPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.RED, 1));
        wrapPanel.setLayout(new WrapLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
        wrapPanel.add(new JButton("New button"));
        wrapPanel.add(new JButton("New button"));

        boxPanel.add(Box.createGlue());     
        boxPanel.add(wrapPanel);
        boxPanel.add(Box.createGlue());     

        add(boxPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can center a JPanel containing a FlowLayout by this code

```
setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
```

Comment: This will only center the JPanel horizontally but not vertically. I want the JPanel to be centered in both orientations.